# Integral with a substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I must calculate a following integral

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}$$

with a subsitution like this $x = \frac{1}{t}, t<0$

I'm on this step
$$\int \frac{dt}{\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{t^{2} + 1}}$$

I don't know what I should do now... (or maybe it's wrong).

Comment: Is the substitution $x=1/t$ imperative, or could you use a different one?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's imperative.

Comment: Write the integrand as $\displaystyle\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2 + 1}} = \frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{t^2 + 1}$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how did you get it? Could you explain it a little more?

Comment: @user12465:  What happens when you divide $1$ by $\frac{a}{b}$?

Comment: @user12465: $\dfrac{1}{1/t}=t$

Comment: @user6312, @Américo Tavares I know it :), but it didn't make any difference then. I didn't know what I should do next.

Comment: @user6312: I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $t<0$, the substitution $x=1/t$ transforms the integral into

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{1}{\left( \frac{1}{t}\right) ^{2}\sqrt{1+\left( \frac{1}{t}%
\right) ^{2}}}\left( -\frac{1}{t^{2}}\right) dt &=&-\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+%
\frac{1}{t^{2}}}}dt \\
&=&-\int \frac{\sqrt{t^{2}}}{\sqrt{t^{2}+1}}dt \\
&=&-\int \frac{\left\vert t\right\vert }{\sqrt{t^{2}+1}}dt=\int \frac{t}{%
\sqrt{t^{2}+1}}dt \\
&=&\sqrt{t^{2}+1}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thank you! I've gotten the same result with the substitution proposed by @Hans Lundmark.

Comment: @user12465: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't see right away how to integrate it, try substituting $s=t^2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Making the substitution $t=\tan\theta =\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$, we see that the integral is $$\int \frac{1}{\tan \theta} d\theta=\int \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}d\theta.$$  Since $d\left(\sin \theta\right)=-\cos \theta$ we can write this antiderivative as $-\ln \sin \theta $.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Why substitute further? you can directly integrate now.